# PHP - How to get info from a newly created user

Tags: php, web

Im totally new to php but have been programming for around 5 years in C#.

Im struggling to get my head around some of the basics in this.

So i have an application that will take info from a user to create a new entry in my db for their new account. Once the account is created i then need to know their unique id.

Should all of this be done in one php file? Or should i create another php file to grab the id?

If i take the second approach how do i know what the email was they used in the first php file? In C# i get you can create references, and reference other variables but how do you do this in PHP? In my understanding if i use the include in any file it will execute all the code in that file?

Thanks

John

Here is the PHP

```
<?php
/// Check to make sure there is data in these fields
/// Only accept user when they have confirmed thier email
error_reporting('E_All');
include 'db_header.php';
$error = '';
$firstName = $_GET['firstName'];
$lastName = $_GET['lastName'];
global $email = $_GET['email'];
$password = $_GET['password'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO Player (FirstName, LastName, Email, Password)
VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$email', '$password')";


// Here i need to make sure this is correct
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
{
    echo "Welcome " . $firstName . " You are now an Rcader!";
}
else
{
    //echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    $error = $conn->error;
    echo $error;
}
```

Comment: The answer to this depends largely on how you're creating the user and your own personal approach.

Comment: You'll really need to post specific code to answer this, but I typically handle these types of things at the class level, so the object fetches an id automatically after saving to the DB.

Comment: You need to read up on `web sessions` and how cookies are used to persist sessions.  I'd also recommend looking at a few PHP frameworks to see how some modern web applications are structured.  This is not really a great question as is for SO.  Good luck!

Comment: When you do your database insert, you can get the last insert id - then if needed, run another select statement.

Comment: Thanks everyone, i know its not a very good question and that is because i dont understand enough to know what im on about haha. As for the php this is what im currently using. ok im trying to find where to input the code.

Comment: I do all of this on one page, get the email using e.g. `$email = $_POST['email'];` (or GET) and I get the db row id using `mysqli_insert_id`

Comment: Added the code above, I think what is confusing me is conflicting information. Do i use PDO, Procedural, OOP? Mysqli and so on? What is the benefits of each etc?

Comment: Love SO.. when your question results in light scolding in comments but no down votes :)  @JohnEsslemont We see you are trying

Answer (score 2):

In your case when user signup or create new account at this time you use need to use session.

Session variables solve this problem by storing user information to be used across multiple pages (e.g. username, favorite color, etc). By default, session variables last until the user closes the browser.

begins the session, you need to say this at the top of a page or before you call session code

```
session_start();
```

put a user id in the session you want to track who is signup in

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $user_id;
```

Find the signup user id

```
$_SESSION['user']
```

So your page as

```
 if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
 ?>
   // code here
 <?php

 } else {
   ?>
   // code here
   <?php
 }
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed!

Comment: My pleasure helping you :)

Comment: @johnEsslemont You can learn more form here [php sessions](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) and [Php official Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).